Как убрать подсказки серого цвета в Vs
Решил перейти с Vs code на Vs и мне не понравилось то что там есть подсказки серого цвета то есть Vs предлагает мне написать какой-то код и при нажатии таб этот код напишется, мелочь но бесит можно как то убрать что бы был только автокомплит? Зарание спасибо.

Выглядит как copilot. Вы его не включали? (Или они сами по дефолту включают?)

Ничего не включал из коробки так

Лет 5 как отказался от студии, и не виду никаких проблем, так что и вам советую перейти обратно

Отключение серых подсказок (интерактивных подсказок)
Откройте настройки:
    Запустите Visual Studio.
    Перейдите в меню Tools (Инструменты) и выберите Options (Параметры).

Перейдите в настройки редактора:
    В открывшемся окне настроек, разверните Text Editor (Текстовый редактор).
    Затем выберите язык, который вы используете (например, C#, C++, Python и т.д.).
    Если вы не видите нужный язык, выберите All Languages (Все языки).

Настройки IntelliSense:
    Найдите раздел General (Общие) в настройках выбранного языка.
    Убедитесь, что Show completion list after a character is typed (Показывать список завершения после ввода символа) и Show completion list on a character that is typed (Показывать список завершения на введенный символ) включены.
    Отключите опцию Show completion list after a character is typed (Показывать список завершения после ввода символа), если она включена. Это может помочь отключить серые подсказки при вводе.

Изменение настроек подсказок:
    Перейдите в Advanced (Дополнительно) или IntelliSense (в зависимости от языка) и найдите опции, связанные с отображением подсказок.
    Вы можете отключить опции, такие как Show completion list after a character is typed (Показывать список завершения после ввода символа) или Show completion list on a character that is typed (Показывать список завершения на введенный символ).

Сохраните изменения:
    Нажмите OK, чтобы сохранить изменения и закрыть окно настроек.

Установка других параметров IntelliSense
Если вы хотите настроить другие параметры IntelliSense, вы можете рассмотреть следующие варианты:
Изменение способа отображения: В разделе Options (Параметры) вы также можете настроить, как отображается подсказка, включая цвет и стиль.
Отключение некоторых функций: Если вы хотите полностью отключить некоторые функции, вы можете взглянуть на другие параметры в разделе IntelliSense.

Копилот в России заблокирован, также как и недавнее отключение от Swift, особо не позволяет его использовать. Автор судя по всему не использовал VPN чтобы использовать 1 месяц бесплатного копилота.
В случае если не интеллисенс, то посмотрите плагины что установили и отключите те же по типу копилота... Такие как табнайн например.
